# admin htaccess exceptions

Tags: joomla

I have been advised several times for security reasons to create an htaccess for the admin folder in Joomla. However I have yet to figure out how to do this without breaking civicrm. I have included all exceptions that I currently have in the htaccess in the root folder but dashlets do not work, nor can event pages be viewed. I do not know a lot about htaccess, can anyone give me the correct exceptions? Thanks very much